# How to Add related entites to database using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying add the cart to database but don't know how to add related `Entities`
My related tables are ( `carts` , `products` , `productoptions` , `options`)

[image: Here is Database Diagram]

How Can I add or Update those tables at the same time? And how can I set Foreign keys to related `Tables`

thanks...

Comment: You can follow the Microsoft Documentation related to that => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data

Comment: You can't update multiple tables at the same time, a DML statement can only affect one table. You would need to perform multiple DML operations; one against each table.

Comment: You need navigation properties (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships)

Comment: @Larnu I think your comment could confuse the issue. One call to SaveChanges will make all the changes that the context is currently tracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will create models for each of your tables (see below)

Then if you add just a child you will have to add it with the foreig nkey property populated

```
var test = childObj { parentPropertyId = parentPropertyIdValue}
```

If you add parent and child together you can just add and entity mework will take care of that. For example:

```
var test = new parentObj {
someProperty = someValue,
childProperty = new childObj{
//here will not have to populate the parentPropertyId
    }

}
```

See sample models for your above tables

Use the [Key] attribute to specify your primary key

Use the [ForeignKey] attribute above your related entity property to specify which property to use as foreign key

Use an ICollection to access the children of an object

```
 public class Carts
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Userid { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Products> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Products
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string StockCode { get; set; }
    public int CartId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(CartId))]
    public Carts Cart { get; set; }

}

public class ProductOptions
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int OptionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ProductId))]
    public Products Products { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(OptionId))]
    public  Options Options { get; set; }
}

public class Options
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int GrandParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: First of All thanks for answer.  I use Asp.Net WebAPI how can I add as nested. My Code to Add is like:   `public IActionResult AddToCart(Cart cart, Product product, ProductOption productOption)
        {
            var result = _cartService.Add(cart);
        }`